# Animate Illustrated Images

Tags: gratis, animation

I'm looking for some free software that can make an illustration into a video. So if I have an illustration of a carrot I want the software to make a video zooming in and out of the carrot, making the carrot spin, bounce, expand, shrink and preferably many more effects.

Preferrably this should work with .png and transparent backgrounds, so you animate only the carrot and select a background image that is still (or has a different animation).

Preferably it should be web based or on windows, but android and macOS are also okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of "png-tuber" applications? They are quick and easy tools for animating still images. I haven't used one, but with a quick Google search, I found [veadotube](https://veado.tube/en/), which is supported on Windows. I wouldn't be surprised if you could find a web-based or Android app too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).